# Overwrite JLabels when different selections are selected in JComboBox?

Tags: java, swing, combobox

I have a JComboBox that retrieves it's data from a database (Ahmed, Mahmoud, Ali).

when I select the first option, it displays the information of Ahmed that I retrieved from the database and shown in a JFrame as text of a JLabels

The problem is that when I choose the second option, it overwrites the informations of Ahmed with Mahmoud's and display it above.

```
    JPanel calendarPanel = new JPanel();
    calendarPanel.setToolTipText("");
    calendarPanel.setBorder(new TitledBorder(null, "Calendar Panel", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, null));
    calendarPanel.setBounds(12, 13, 878, 254);
    frameDetails.getContentPane().add(calendarPanel);
    calendarPanel.setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblSat = new JLabel("Saturday");
    lblSat.setBounds(12, 70, 56, 16);
    calendarPanel.add(lblSat);

    JLabel lblSun = new JLabel("Sunday");
    lblSun.setBounds(12, 99, 56, 16);
    calendarPanel.add(lblSun);

    JLabel lblMon = new JLabel("Monday");
    lblMon.setBounds(12, 128, 56, 16);
    calendarPanel.add(lblMon);

    JLabel lblTus = new JLabel("Tuesday");
    lblTus.setBounds(12, 157, 56, 16);
    calendarPanel.add(lblTus);

    JLabel lblWes = new JLabel("Wednesday");
    lblWes.setBounds(12, 187, 77, 16);
    calendarPanel.add(lblWes);

    JLabel lblThur = new JLabel("Thursday");
    lblThur.setBounds(12, 217, 56, 16);
    calendarPanel.add(lblThur);

    JPanel panel_12 = new JPanel();
    String statment12 = "select f310t410 from calendar where days='saturday'";
    panelColorChanger(panel_12, statment12); 
    panel_12.setForeground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    panel_12.setBounds(144, 64, 90, 21);
    calendarPanel.add(panel_12);

    JPanel panel_14 = new JPanel();
    String statment14 = "select f420t520 from calendar where days='saturday'";
    panelColorChanger(panel_14, statment14); 
    panel_14.setForeground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    panel_14.setBounds(300, 64, 90, 21);
    calendarPanel.add(panel_14);
    String statment16 = "select f530t630 from calendar where days='saturday'";
    String statment18 = "select f640t740 from calendar where days='saturday'";
    String statment110 = "select f750t850 from calendar where days='saturday'";

    JPanel panel_22 = new JPanel();
    panel_22.setForeground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    String statment22 = "select f310t410 from calendar where days='sunday'";
    panelColorChanger(panel_22, statment22); 
    panel_22.setBounds(145, 92, 90, 24);
    calendarPanel.add(panel_22);

    JPanel panel_24 = new JPanel();
    panel_24.setForeground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    String statment24 = "select f420t520 from calendar where days='sunday'";
    panelColorChanger(panel_24, statment24); 
    panel_24.setBounds(301, 92, 90, 24);
    calendarPanel.add(panel_24);
    String statment26 = "select f530t630 from calendar where days='sunday'";
    String statment28 = "select f640t740 from calendar where days='sunday'";
    String statment210 = "select f750t850 from calendar where days='sunday'";

    JPanel panel_32 = new JPanel();
    panel_32.setForeground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    String statment32 = "select f310t410 from calendar where days='monday'";
    panelColorChanger(panel_32, statment32); 
    panel_32.setBounds(145, 122, 90, 22);
    calendarPanel.add(panel_32);

    JPanel panel_34 = new JPanel();
    panel_34.setForeground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    String statment34 = "select f420t520 from calendar where days='monday'";
    panelColorChanger(panel_34, statment34); 
    panel_34.setBounds(301, 122, 90, 22);
    calendarPanel.add(panel_34);
    String statment36 = "select f530t630 from calendar where days='monday'";
    String statment38 = "select f640t740 from calendar where days='monday'";
    String statment310 = "select f750t850 from calendar where days='monday'";

    JPanel panel_42 = new JPanel();
    panel_42.setForeground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    String statment42 = "select f310t410 from calendar where days='tuesday'";
    panelColorChanger(panel_42, statment42);
    panel_42.setBounds(145, 149, 90, 23);
    calendarPanel.add(panel_42);

    JPanel panel_44 = new JPanel();
    panel_44.setForeground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    String statment44 = "select f420t520 from calendar where days='tuesday'";
    panelColorChanger(panel_44, statment44); 
    panel_44.setBounds(301, 149, 90, 23);
    calendarPanel.add(panel_44);
    String statment46 = "select f530t630 from calendar where days='tuesday'";
    String statment48 = "select f640t740 from calendar where days='tuesday'";
    String statment410 = "select f750t850 from calendar where days='tuesday'";

    JPanel panel_52 = new JPanel();
    panel_52.setForeground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    String statment52 = "select f310t410 from calendar where days='wednesday'";
    panelColorChanger(panel_52, statment52); 
    panel_52.setBounds(145, 179, 90, 25);
    calendarPanel.add(panel_52);

    JPanel panel_54 = new JPanel();
    panel_54.setForeground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    String statment54 = "select f420t520 from calendar where days='wednesday'";
    panelColorChanger(panel_54, statment54);
    panel_54.setBounds(301, 179, 90, 25);
    calendarPanel.add(panel_54);
    String statment56 = "select f530t630 from calendar where days='wednesday'";
    String statment58 = "select f640t740 from calendar where days='wednesday'";
    String statment510 = "select f750t850 from calendar where days='wednesday'";

    JPanel panel_62 = new JPanel();
    panel_62.setForeground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    String statment62 = "select f310t410 from calendar where days='thursday'";
    panelColorChanger(panel_62, statment62); 
    panel_62.setBounds(145, 209, 90, 24);
    calendarPanel.add(panel_62);

    JPanel panel_64 = new JPanel();
    panel_64.setForeground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    String statment64 = "select f420t520 from calendar where days='thursday'";
    panelColorChanger(panel_64, statment64); 
    panel_64.setBounds(301, 209, 90, 24);
    calendarPanel.add(panel_64);
    String statment66 = "select f530t630 from calendar where days='thursday'";
    String statment68 = "select f640t740 from calendar where days='thursday'";
    String statment610 = "select f750t850 from calendar where days='thursday'";


    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////Calendar Table


    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////Add Patient


    patientPanel = new JPanel();
    patientPanel.setLayout(null);
    patientPanel.setBorder(new TitledBorder(null, "Add New Patient", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, null));
    patientPanel.setBounds(12, 280, 1304, 163);
    frameDetails.getContentPane().add(patientPanel);

    lblName = new JLabel("Name");
    lblName.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
    lblName.setBounds(31, 24, 56, 16);
    patientPanel.add(lblName);

    txtName = new JTextField();
    txtName.setBounds(120, 24, 240, 22);
    patientPanel.add(txtName);
    txtName.setColumns(10);

    lblAge = new JLabel("Age");
    lblAge.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
    lblAge.setBounds(31, 59, 56, 23);
    patientPanel.add(lblAge);

    lblMobile = new JLabel("Mobile");
    lblMobile.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
    lblMobile.setBounds(31, 95, 56, 16);
    patientPanel.add(lblMobile);

    txtAge = new JTextField();
    txtAge.setColumns(10);
    txtAge.setBounds(120, 59, 240, 22);
    patientPanel.add(txtAge);

    txtMobile = new JTextField();
    txtMobile.setColumns(10);
    txtMobile.setBounds(120, 95, 240, 22);
    patientPanel.add(txtMobile);

    JComboBox comboBoxDays = new JComboBox();
    List<String> arrDays = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    //arrDays.add("44444444");
    //comboBoxDays.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(arrDays.toArray()));
    comboBoxDays.setBounds(474, 24, 127, 22);
    patientPanel.add(comboBoxDays);

    JComboBox comboBoxTime = new JComboBox();
    List<String> arrTime = new ArrayList<String>();
    arrTime.add("");
    comboBoxTime.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(arrTime.toArray()));

    // add time available to list of times when select a day
    comboBoxDays.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub



        }
    });



    comboBoxTime.setBounds(474, 61, 127, 22);
    patientPanel.add(comboBoxTime);


    JLabel lblDay = new JLabel("Day");
    lblDay.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
    lblDay.setBounds(389, 27, 56, 16);
    patientPanel.add(lblDay);

    JLabel lblTime = new JLabel("Time");
    lblTime.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
    lblTime.setBounds(389, 64, 56, 16);
    patientPanel.add(lblTime);

    JLabel lblDescription = new JLabel("Description");
    lblDescription.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
    lblDescription.setBounds(31, 132, 77, 22);
    patientPanel.add(lblDescription);

    txtDescription = new JTextField();
    txtDescription.setColumns(10);
    txtDescription.setBounds(120, 132, 240, 22);
    patientPanel.add(txtDescription);

    JButton btnAddNewPatient = new JButton("Add New Patient");
    btnAddNewPatient.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            String radioText = "Not Confirmed";

            try {
                if (txtName.getText().isEmpty() || txtAge.getText().isEmpty() || txtMobile.getText().isEmpty() || txtDescription.getText().isEmpty() || comboBoxDays.getSelectedItem().toString().isEmpty() || comboBoxTime.getSelectedItem().toString().isEmpty())
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please fill empty fields!");
                }

                else {

                    //to insert the patient name with his time into table patientCalender
                    String statInsertPatient = "insert into patientCalendar values ('"+txtName.getText()+"','"+comboBoxDays.getSelectedItem().toString()+"','"+comboBoxTime.getSelectedItem().toString()+"')";


                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


    });
    btnAddNewPatient.setBounds(630, 24, 194, 58);
    patientPanel.add(btnAddNewPatient);


    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////Add Patient


    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////Details table



    detailsPanel = new JPanel();
    detailsPanel.setLayout(null);
    detailsPanel.setToolTipText("");
    detailsPanel.setBorder(new TitledBorder(null, "Details", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, null));
    detailsPanel.setBounds(12, 456, 1304, 252);
    frameDetails.getContentPane().add(detailsPanel);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setBounds(12, 32, 940, 207);
    detailsPanel.add(scrollPane);

    detailsTable = new JTable();
    scrollPane.setViewportView(detailsTable);
    detailsTable.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
        new Object[][] {
        },
        new String[] {
        }
    ));
    detailsTable.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)));

    textFieldSearch = new JTextField();
    textFieldSearch.setToolTipText("Enter Patient Name");
    textFieldSearch.setBounds(1034, 45, 179, 29);
    detailsPanel.add(textFieldSearch);
    textFieldSearch.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {

        }
        }
    );
    textFieldSearch.setColumns(10);

    JButton btnDelete = new JButton("Delete");
    btnDelete.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                String query = "delete from patient where name='"+textFieldSearch.getText() +"'    ";
                PreparedStatement pst= connection.prepareStatement(query);

                pst.execute();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null  , "Deleted ");


            pst.close();



            } catch(Exception e1) {

                e1.printStackTrace();

            }
        }

        }
    );
    btnDelete.setBounds(1065, 133, 116, 40);
    detailsPanel.add(btnDelete);


    JButton btnShow = new JButton("Show All");
    btnShow.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            try {
                String query = "select * from patient ";
                PreparedStatement pst= connection.prepareStatement(query);
                ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

                detailsTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

            } catch(Exception el) {
                el.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
    btnShow.setBounds(1065, 178, 116, 42);
    detailsPanel.add(btnShow);

    JButton btnSearch = new JButton("Search");
    btnSearch.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            try {
                String query = "select * from patient where name=?";
                PreparedStatement pst= connection.prepareStatement(query);
                pst.setString(1, textFieldSearch.getText() );
                ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

                detailsTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));


                pst.close();



            } catch(Exception e1) {

                e1.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
    });
    btnSearch.setBounds(1065, 87, 116, 40);
    detailsPanel.add(btnSearch);

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////Details table

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////Set Calendar

    JPanel setCalendarPanel = new JPanel();
    setCalendarPanel.setBorder(new TitledBorder(null, "Set Calender Days", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, null));
    setCalendarPanel.setBounds(902, 24, 260, 243);
    frameDetails.getContentPane().add(setCalendarPanel);
    setCalendarPanel.setLayout(null);

    chckbxSaturday = new JCheckBox("Saturday");
    chckbxSaturday.setBounds(8, 54, 160, 25);
    setCalendarPanel.add(chckbxSaturday);

    chckbxSunday = new JCheckBox("Sunday");
    chckbxSunday.setBounds(8, 84, 160, 25);
    setCalendarPanel.add(chckbxSunday);

    chckbxMonday = new JCheckBox("Monday");
    chckbxMonday.setBounds(8, 116, 160, 25);
    setCalendarPanel.add(chckbxMonday);

    chckbxTuesday = new JCheckBox("Tuesday");
    chckbxTuesday.setBounds(8, 146, 160, 25);
    setCalendarPanel.add(chckbxTuesday);

    chckbxWednesday = new JCheckBox("Wednesday");
    chckbxWednesday.setBounds(8, 178, 160, 25);
    setCalendarPanel.add(chckbxWednesday);

    chckbxThursday = new JCheckBox("Thursday");
    chckbxThursday.setBounds(8, 209, 87, 25);
    setCalendarPanel.add(chckbxThursday);

    JLabel lblPleaseSelectAvailable = new JLabel("Please select available days: ");
    lblPleaseSelectAvailable.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
    lblPleaseSelectAvailable.setBounds(8, 19, 239, 37);
    setCalendarPanel.add(lblPleaseSelectAvailable);

    //////////////////////////////////
    //Set selected days on launch to add the selected days to comboBoxDays
    String sqlquery11 = "select f310t410 from calendar WHERE calendar.days='saturday'";
    String panelColor11= connect2databaseWithexecuteQuery(sqlquery11);
    if (panelColor11.contentEquals("white") || panelColor11.contentEquals("green") || panelColor11.contentEquals("red")){
        chckbxSaturday.setSelected(true);
    }
    String sqlquery22 = "select f310t410 from calendar WHERE calendar.days='sunday'";
    String panelColor22= connect2databaseWithexecuteQuery(sqlquery22);
    if (panelColor22.contentEquals("white") || panelColor22.contentEquals("green") || panelColor22.contentEquals("red"))
    {
        chckbxSunday.setSelected(true);
    }
    String sqlquery33 = "select f310t410 from calendar WHERE calendar.days='monday'";
    String panelColor33= connect2databaseWithexecuteQuery(sqlquery33);
    if (panelColor33.contentEquals("white") || panelColor33.contentEquals("green") || panelColor33.contentEquals("red"))
    {
        chckbxMonday.setSelected(true);
    }
    String sqlquery44 = "select f310t410 from calendar WHERE calendar.days='tuesday'";
    String panelColor44= connect2databaseWithexecuteQuery(sqlquery44);
    if (panelColor44.contentEquals("white") || panelColor44.contentEquals("green") || panelColor44.contentEquals("red"))
    {
        chckbxTuesday.setSelected(true);
    }
    String sqlquery55 = "select f310t410 from calendar WHERE calendar.days='wednesday'";
    String panelColor55= connect2databaseWithexecuteQuery(sqlquery55);
    if (panelColor55.contentEquals("white") || panelColor55.contentEquals("green") || panelColor55.contentEquals("red"))
    {
        chckbxWednesday.setSelected(true);
    }
    String sqlquery66 = "select f310t410 from calendar WHERE calendar.days='thursday'";
    String panelColor66= connect2databaseWithexecuteQuery(sqlquery66);
    if (panelColor66.contentEquals("white") || panelColor66.contentEquals("green") || panelColor66.contentEquals("red")){
        chckbxThursday.setSelected(true);
    }


    ///***************
    //check if checkboxes selected to add their text to comboBoxDays
    arrDays.add("");
    if (chckbxSaturday.isSelected()){
        arrDays.add("Saturday");
    }
    if (chckbxSunday.isSelected()){
        arrDays.add("Sunday");
    }
    if (chckbxMonday.isSelected()){
        arrDays.add("Monday");
    }
    if (chckbxTuesday.isSelected()){
        arrDays.add("Tuesday");
    }
    if (chckbxWednesday.isSelected()){
        arrDays.add("Wednesday");
    }
    if (chckbxThursday.isSelected()){
        arrDays.add("Thursday");
    }
    comboBoxDays.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(arrDays.toArray()));

    JButton btnUpdatePatientStatus = new JButton("Update Patient Status");
    btnUpdatePatientStatus.setBounds(843, 21, 194, 58);
    patientPanel.add(btnUpdatePatientStatus);
    ////////////////////////////////


    JButton btnSetCalender = new JButton("Set Calender"); // Button Set Calendar
    btnSetCalender.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            if (chckbxSaturday.isSelected()){
                //access database
                //make colms of Saturday all white

                if(arrDays.contains("Saturday") == false){
                    arrDays.add("Saturday");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //access database
                //make colms of Saturday all gray

                if(arrDays.contains("Saturday") == true){
                    arrDays.remove("Saturday");
                }
            }
            if (chckbxSunday.isSelected()){
                //access database
                //make colms of Sunday all white

                if(arrDays.contains("Sunday") == false){
                    arrDays.add("Sunday");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //access database
                //make colms of Sunday all gray

                if(arrDays.contains("Sunday") == true){
                    arrDays.remove("Sunday");
                }
            }
            if (chckbxMonday.isSelected()){
                //access database
                //make colms of Monday all white

                if(arrDays.contains("Monday") == false){
                    arrDays.add("Monday");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //access database
                //make colms of Monday all gray

                if(arrDays.contains("Monday") == true){
                    arrDays.remove("Monday");
                }
            }
            if (chckbxTuesday.isSelected()){
                //access database
                //make colms of Tuesday all white

                if(arrDays.contains("Tuesday") == false){
                    arrDays.add("Tuesday");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //access database
                //make colms of Tuesday all gray

                if(arrDays.contains("Tuesday") == true){
                    arrDays.remove("Tuesday");
                }
            }
            if (chckbxWednesday.isSelected()){
                //access database
                //make colms of Wednesday all white

                if(arrDays.contains("Wednesday") == false){
                    arrDays.add("Wednesday");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //access database
                //make colms of Wednesday all gray

                if(arrDays.contains("Wednesday") == true){
                    arrDays.remove("Wednesday");
                }
            }
            if (chckbxThursday.isSelected()){
                //access database
                //make colms of Thursday all white

                if(arrDays.contains("Thursday") == false){
                    arrDays.add("Thursday");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //access database
                //make colms of Thursday all gray

                if(arrDays.contains("Thursday") == true){
                    arrDays.remove("Thursday");
                }
            }


            comboBoxDays.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(arrDays.toArray())); //Days ComboBox


            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Calendar Set Successfully!","Calender Set",JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION);


        }
    });
    btnSetCalender.setBounds(104, 203, 146, 37);
    setCalendarPanel.add(btnSetCalender);

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////Add Doctor

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBorder(new TitledBorder(null, "Add/Choose Doctor", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, null));
    panel.setBounds(1174, 24, 162, 241);
    frameDetails.getContentPane().add(panel);
    panel.setLayout(null);

    comboBoxDoctorsNames = new JComboBox();
    arrDoctors = new ArrayList<String>();       
    arrDoctors.add("");
    arrDoctors.addAll(getMultiDocsNames());
    System.out.println(getMultiDocsNames());
    comboBoxDoctorsNames.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(arrDoctors.toArray()));
    comboBoxDoctorsNames.setBounds(12, 49, 138, 22);
    panel.add(comboBoxDoctorsNames);

    comboBoxDoctorsNames.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String selectedDoctor = comboBoxDoctorsNames.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String query = "select * from '"+selectedDoctor+"'";
            List<String> arrColms = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<JLabel> arrLbls = new ArrayList<JLabel>();
            int boundTimelbl = 162;


            try {
                //access the table and get colms names
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:DoctorProject.db");
                Statement statement = con.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(query);
                ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
                int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();
                // The column count starts from 1
                for (int i = 2; i <= columnCount; i++ ) {
                  String name = rsmd.getColumnName(i);
                  // Do stuff with name
                  if(arrColms.contains(name) == false){
                      arrColms.add(name);
                  }
                }

                for (String colm : arrColms) {
                    mTimelbl = new JLabel();
                    mTimelbl.setText(colm);
                    mTimelbl.setBounds(boundTimelbl, 35, 56, 16);
                    boundTimelbl = boundTimelbl + 156;
                    arrLbls.add(mTimelbl);

                }

                  Component[] components = calendarPanel.getComponents();
                    for (Component component : components) {
                        if (component instanceof JLabel) {
                            jPanel1.remove(component);
                        }
                    }
                for (JLabel mLbl : arrLbls) {
                    calendarPanel.add(mLbl);
                }

                calendarPanel.revalidate();
                calendarPanel.repaint();


                System.out.println(arrColms);
                con.close();

            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }



        }
    });
```

Comment: do you have a  table called ahmed, Mahmoud, ect ....???

Comment: Yea and these tables created by users

Comment: your issue is due to the fact that you are adding the labels to the panel without removing the previous ones

Comment: How to remove the previous ones by just choose another selection from combo-Box ?!

Comment: if my solution is working upvote and validate it else comment about the new issue.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `calendarPanel.removeAll();` before to remove all components

```
            for (JLabel mLbl : arrLbls) {
                calendarPanel.add(mLbl);
            }
```

or use before the loop that I mentioned to remove labels only

```
  Component[] components = calendarPanel.getComponents();
    for (Component component : components) {
        if (component instanceof JLabel) {
            calendarPanel.remove(component);
        }
    }

        for (JLabel mLbl : arrLbls) {
            calendarPanel.add(mLbl);
        }
```

but to remove our last added Labels we should first store them somewhere so first we create a List of JLabels

```
private final List<JLabel> myPreviousAddedLabels = new ArrayList<JLabel>();

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String selectedDoctor = comboBoxDoctorsNames.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

then you should use this

```
            for (JLabel component : myPreviousAddedLabels) {

                    calendarPanel.remove(component);

            }

            myPreviousAddedLabels.clear();

            for (JLabel mLbl : arrLbls) {
                myPreviousAddedLabels.add(mLbl);
                calendarPanel.add(mLbl);
            }

            calendarPanel.revalidate();
            calendarPanel.repaint();
```

Comment: My calenderPanel contain JLabel and Jpanel
Your code remove both of them
How can i remove the labels only

Comment: please provide your jpanel creation code, so I can be more efficient .

Comment: use the second alternative is the better way instanceof will check for the component class this case we remove labels only.

Comment: you mean by JPanel1 the name of Jpanel or what ?!
and i have replaced the code above

Comment: is calendar I will provide a new solution because your calendar panel is full of labels removing all labels mean you will loose your calendar, first we have to use the previous added label in the remove

Comment: sure i am already upvoted but i have less than 15 reputation so its recorded but not displayed here ..